# Leaflet map: on click changing color of all markers

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, markers

I am definitely missing some js syntax to achieve this, but hard-googling did not lead me to any conclusion.

I want to toggle markers color on click. I got the sprites predefined as variables "greenIcon" and "defaultIcon". Everything works for a single marker, I can toggle it back and forth with this:

```
.on('click', function(e) {
if (this.getIcon() != greenIcon) {
  this.setIcon(greenIcon);
} else {
  this.setIcon(defaultIcon);
}
})
```

As simple as that. The thing I want to achieve is that on click on one marker, others change to "defaultIcon", and only this one toggles. Is there anything I could use apart from "this." in shown example? Like, all.setIcon(defaultIcon)?

My markers properties are definied in var array, named "points":

```
    var points = [
    {latlng: [54.351194, 18.654101], title: "F-225", name: "Marker 1"},
    {latlng: [54.351194, 18.658101], title: "F-226", name: "Marker 2",
];
points.forEach(function(p) {
    L.marker(p.latlng, {
        title: p.title, riseOnHover: true
    })
    .addTo(map)
    .on('click', function(e) {
    // all.setIcon(defaultIcon);
  })
    .bindPopup(popupName);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have some CodeSandbox where you can produce the issue?

Comment: @radulle https://jsfiddle.net/MattGnys/ns4bcqek/
It's kinda messy at that moment but I hope it will show the idea. I marked the place where I would love all markers to go default. Cheers!

Comment: I edited the fiddle, please check the https://jsfiddle.net/vz7jmnqs/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding markers push them into an array. `const markers = []` somewhere at the beginning and `than markers.push(L.marker(...` Than you can manipulate all by iterating over the array or single one if you add some kind of unique key to your points. Current one you can access with `this` too.

I edited the fiddle, please check the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vz7jmnqs/2/).

Comment: No problem, if you plan to have more types of markers/icons I would recommend using a plugin Leaflet Awesome Markers (https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers) to simplify styling. There are others available on https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html but I haven't tried them all.